# DLookup returning null despite same code working in another form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the code below to find the most recent values from a record, so this instance gets the [Process No] where the [Time] field equals my `DMax` value. For some bizarre reason it's suddenly stopped working and only returns null now.

This same code worked last week, but since an entry was made over the weekend (by someone else) all similar `DLookup` statements only return null values. The same code still works in my other forms and I've since deleted what I though was the dodgy record but no luck.

```
DMaxTime = DMax("[Time]", "Daily Oven/Product Record")

'Find last Process No entered
lastProcNoLookup = DLookup("[Process No]", "Daily Oven/Product Record", "[Time] = #" & DMaxTime & "#")
```

*DMaxTime and lastProcNoLookup are both variants

Comment: Add `Debug.Print "[Time] = #" & DMaxTime & "#"` to the line before `'Find last Process`.  Then what does that change show you in the Immediate window after you run the revised code?  (Ctrl+g will open the Immediate window.)

Comment: It gives me `[Time] = #03/02/2015 10:40:46#` which is the time of the last entry.

Comment: Good.  I assume that is today's date in *dd/mm/yyyy* format.  Then what do you see from this query in the query designer? `SELECT [Process No] FROM [Daily Oven/Product Record] WHERE [Time] = #2015-02-03 10:40:46#`

Comment: Yeah that gives me the correct number associated with that time. I don't get why my DLookup gives a null though. The table name is spelled correctly and everything.

Comment: Your `DLookup` was asking for a value from Mar 2, 2015.

Comment: The `[Time]` is all taken from `Now()`, do I need to change the format of the input or anything or will it be okay?

Comment: `Now()` returns a Date/Time value and does not inherently include any format.  When you give the db engine a string representation of any Date/Time value, always format the date piece of that string as *yyyy-m-d* to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the Date/Time value for the `DLookup` *Criteria* option, format the date part of that value as *yyyy-m-d*.

```vb
'Find last Process No entered
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "[Time] = " & Format(DMaxTime, "\#yyyy-m-d hh:nn:ss\#")
Debug.Print strCriteria
lastProcNoLookup = DLookup("[Process No]", "Daily Oven/Product Record", strCriteria)
```

---

Explanation:

When you give the db engine a date string in *dd/mm/yyyy* format, Access can interpret it correctly if the string does not represent a valid date in *mm/dd/yyyy* format.

For example, since there is no month 25, the db engine knows *#25-1-2015#* must mean *Jan, 1 2015*.  So this query interprets the value as you intend.

```
SELECT Year(#25-1-2015#) AS [Year], Format(#25-1-2015#, 'mmm d, yyyy') AS Formatted_date

Year Formatted_date
---- --------------
2015 Jan 25, 2015
```

However *#3-2-2015#* will be interpreted as *Mar 2* instead of *Feb 3, 2015*:

```
SELECT Year(#3-2-2015#) AS [Year], Format(#3-2-2015#, 'mmm d, yyyy') AS Formatted_date

Year Formatted_date
---- --------------
2015 Mar 2, 2015
```

You can avoid such confusion by always giving the db engine dates in *yyyy-m-d* format.